# Excelsior Jet load librarys at runtime

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime, bytecode, native-code

I am using excelsior jet to compile my application, mainly for protection reasons.
It takes about half an hour just for compiling the library's. Is it possible to not recompile them every time or load them at run time as jar from a folder? Its really annoying to compile half an hour for every update.

Answer (score 1):

We really have to do something about compilation time. Problem is, the bottleneck is in a piece of sophisticated legacy code that is quite difficult to replace...

In the meantime, see the chapters "Dynamic Linking" and "Mixed Compilation Model" in the *[Excelsior JET User's Guide](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/docs/)*.

Comment: i dont really see how to use it in the documentation.

Comment: For dynamic linking, see `samples\MultiComponent` in your Excelsior JET installation directory.

Comment: please add this to GUI, i use 33 librarys in my project and now need to create a .prj for each.

Comment: I'd rather have us make the compiler utilize all cores... Also, you don't need 33 .prj files - just place all your library jars in one .prj.

Comment: (1+) 2k20, Excelsior JET discontinued, and still this post mentioning the existence of the sample helped me a lot. I wish one day excelsior jet will come back, or just be open source.